# UWP Page Preload ( Is it possible to preload the contents of a page )

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, preload

I'm working on a Windows 10 app. and i created map in my second page.. but it is too slow.. Is it possible to preload the contents of a page before displaying it to the user so that the transition from page x to page y is smooth?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is probably to not make it a page at all; instead, have the map on the page you are starting from, but have its `Opacity` be zero. Then when you want to show it, set the `Opacity` to one. This if course means you pay the cost of loading the map even if the user never wants to view it, but it makes viewing instant.

Sample XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <Button Content="go to map" Click="GoToMap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  <Grid x:Name="mapLayer" xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <maps:MapControl />
    <Button Content="back" Click="HideMap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And matching code:

```
private void GoToMap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  mapLayer.Opacity = 1;
  mapLayer.IsHitTestVisible = true;
}

private void HideMap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  mapLayer.Opacity = 0;
  mapLayer.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. is there any option like secondpage.preload() or anything like that ? because i need to load secondpage when user in firstpage.

Comment: Why does it need to be a separate page?

Comment: because you dont know to my  design.. my customer want it seperate.

Comment: Does it have to be a `Page` object or does it just have to look like it's on a separate page?

Comment: they are two different page view i have a main view and when i click map button my second page opening but map coming very slowly.. because of this i need to do it preload in my first page..

Comment: Added simple example

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible, all pages in uwp apps will be rendered when  you navigated to some page.

But you can prepare the data before to navigate to your second page maybe you can save this data in the local storage and load the data in the method OnNavigatedTo  in your second page it would be better.

Comment: i guess i cant storage these data because i am using yandex traffic information.